# Сайт не индексируется в Google, поможет ли дополнительный домен?

Tags: поиск, поисковые-системы

Сайт не индексируется в Google. Яндекс еле-еле через много месяцев все же проиндексировал (не все страницы). Лежащие на поверхности объяснения изучены - не помогло. Поможет ли решить проблему дополнительный домен, используемый как алиас основному?